# How to set sensor noise/resolution by code?

Tags: webots

I would like to set the noise & resultion values on startup by code (instead the node viewer). I have been looking through the API for motor and position sensor, but can't find a function that allows to get or set those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly change these values from your controller using the position-sensor or motor API.

However, as a workaround, you can use the Supervisor API (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) to change the value of any field in the scene-tree (e.g. the noise and resolution fields).

Find here a very simple example changing the position field of a light: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-devices#supervisor-wbt